# How to video stream using KIVY for Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, video-streaming, buildozer

How do I video stream using Kivy Python deployed to Android 9.0 tablet with Buildozer?

My goal is load an IP Camera (I am using some public IP camera for testing) and to draw on the frame before displaying it in the application. OpenCV VideoCapture does not work on Android so I am using Kivy Camera/Video/VideoPlayer.

What I came up through research is to use

```
self.camera = Video(source="http://158.58.130.148:80/mjpg/video.mjpg", state='play')
```

which simply enough works on my Ubuntu machine just fine, however, the app only loads a black screen. Research indicates there is a Android Permissions requirement, so I included in the program:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
```

and in the

```
Class CameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
           request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET,
                         Permission.CAMERA,
                         Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                         Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])
```

I initially started working with the Kivy Camera and I am able to successfully deploy and load the camera on the android tablet and manipulate it with Numpy. Which is good. Eventually, ill use Kivy to draw.

Next, I tried working with Kivy Video and/or Video Player to load a video I transferred to the tablets Movies directory at

```
self.camera = Video(source="/storage/emulated/0/Movies/MY-TEST-VIDEO.avi", state='play')
```

But that also loads a black screen. I checked the logs and I don't see any Permission Denied errors so I am lost as to whether this is a Permissions issue, an Encoding issue (like gstreamer, ffpyplayer ffmpeg, which I tried adding to the buildozer.spec file but that didn't work) or a programming issue. I am researching that in Android 9.0 API 28 request permission and confirm request is needed? I am not sure.

See link: [How to handle android runtime permission with kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510030/how-to-handle-android-runtime-permission-with-kivy)

Anyways, any ideas are much appreciated!
Thanks!

---

Python 3.8
Kivy 1.11.1
Buildozer 1.8
Android 9.0

My main.py in my buildozer directory:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.1') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from kivy.uix.video import Video
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer
from kivy.core.window import Window
import numpy as np
#from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest

from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission, check_permission

class CameraApp(App):
    def build(self):

        request_permissions([Permission.INTERNET,
                             Permission.CAMERA,
                             Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                             Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

        self.snapshot = None
        self.root = Widget()
        self.width = Window.size[0]
        self.height = Window.size[1]

        # # CAMERA Works
        #self.camera = Camera(resolution=(640, 480), size=(self.width, self.height), pos=(100, 100), state='play')

        # # IP CAMERA does NOT Work 
        # # Loads black screen
        self.camera = Video(source="http://158.58.130.148:80/mjpg/video.mjpg", state='play')

        # # Video file does NOT Work 
        # self.camera = Video(source='/storage/emulated/0/Movies/MY-TEST-VIDEO.avi', state='play')

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.get_texture1, 1.0 / 25.0)
        return self.root


    def get_texture1(self, event):

        self.snapshot = self.camera.texture

        if self.snapshot != None:

            self.reg = self.snapshot.get_region(0, 0, 50, 50)

            # data processing here on numpy array
            nparr = np.fromstring(self.camera.texture.pixels, dtype=np.uint8)

            # # Just reshape
            # a = np.reshape(nparr, (480, 640, 4))
            
            # # Reshape, Flip, Rotate and make Copy of frame
            frame_reshaped = np.reshape(nparr, (480, 640, 4))
            frame_flipped = np.flip(frame_reshaped, axis=0)
            a = np.rot90(frame_flipped, 1)
            copy = np.copy(a)

            # # Draw on frame
            a[50:50+50, 50:50+50] = 255

            texture = Texture.create(size=(a.shape[1], a.shape[0]), colorfmt='rgba')
            texture.blit_buffer(a.tostring(), bufferfmt='ubyte', colorfmt="rgba")
            texture.flip_vertical()

            self.root.canvas.clear()

            with self.root.canvas:
                Rectangle(texture=texture, size=(a.shape[1], a.shape[0]), pos=(100, 100))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    CameraApp().run()
```

My buildozer.spec

```
 [app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Test App

# (str) Package name
package.name = testApp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.testApp

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
#source.include_exts = py, png, jpg, kv, atlas, avi
source.include_exts = py, png, jpg, kv, atlas, avi, jpeg, mjpg, mjpeg

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
# source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png/*.avi
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,data/*.avi

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy, libshine, libx264, ffpyplayer, ffpyplayer_codecs, certifi
#requirements = python3, kivy, numpy, opencv==4.1.1, ffpyplayer
requirements = python3, kivy, numpy, ffpyplayer, ffpyplayer_codecs, libshine, libx264, ffmpeg, certifi, plyer, httplib2

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, CAMERA, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Running buildozer using:

```
buildozer android clean
buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > log.txt
```

log output (I cannot paste the whole thing because of StackOverflow limitations, so for brevity I am posting the debug and any denied or failed):

```
Warning: failed to apply patch (exit code 1), assuming it is already applied:  src/patches/SDLActivity.java.patch

11-27 12:52:00.366   442   578 E storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
11-27 12:52:28.397   428   801 E installd: Failed to delete /data/app/vmdl495936105.tmp: No such file or directory
11-27 12:52:28.447 22226 24752 I Icing   : Usage reports ok 1, Failed Usage reports 0, indexed 0, rejected 0

--------- beginning of crash
11-27 12:42:00.784  4773  4773 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000000000000450c  /vendor/bin/thermald (main+64)
11-27 12:42:00.784  4773  4773 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000000acd3c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
11-27 12:42:00.810   691   918 W NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 4770
11-27 12:42:01.295   691   691 D BroadcastQueue: Add broadcast <BroadcastRecord{35d7874 u-1 android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED}> into [parallel | background], pending size 0
11-27 12:42:01.296   691  1020 D PowerController: isInVideoCallOrNormalCall:mModeConfigIndex:2,preModeConfigIndex = 2
11-27 12:42:01.297   691   705 D BroadcastQueue: Done with parallel broadcast [background] [BroadcastRecord{35d7874 u-1 android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED}]
11-27 12:42:01.299   921   921 D PowerUI : buckets   .....20 .. 15 .. 5
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : level          100 --> 100
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : status         5 --> 5
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : plugType       2 --> 2
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : invalidCharger 0 --> 0
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : bucket         1 --> 1
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : plugged        true --> true
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : temperature    284
11-27 12:42:01.300   921   921 D PowerUI : health         2 --> 2
11-27 12:42:05.745  4776  4776 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 4776 (thermald), pid 4776 (thermald)
11-27 12:42:05.785  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-27 12:42:05.785  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : Native Crash TIME: 357109353
11-27 12:42:05.785  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
11-27 12:42:05.785  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'VANKYO/S20/S20:9/PPR1.180610.011/44403:user/release-keys'
11-27 12:42:05.785  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
11-27 12:42:05.785  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : pid: 4776, tid: 4776, name: thermald  >>> /vendor/bin/thermald <<<
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : Cause: null pointer dereference
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x0  0000007ae6c2e148  x1  0000005df486a75d  x2  0000000000000061  x3  0000000000000063
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x4  0000000000000000  x5  61061f1d1d110200  x6  0002111d1d1f0661  x7  0000002712444675
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x8  0000000000000000  x9  0000000000000000  x10 0000000000000000  x11 000000000000000e
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x12 0000007ae6c0d888  x13 000000000000000d  x14 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaab  x15 0000007ae6c02f90
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x16 0000005df4885d98  x17 0000007ae7bdf400  x18 0000000000000001  x19 0000007ae6c32780
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x20 0000007ae6c55070  x21 0000007ae6c2e120  x22 0000007ae6c32828  x23 0000007ae6c32810
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x24 0000000000000001  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000000000000002  x27 0000000000000000
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007fea18d1b0
11-27 12:42:05.786  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     sp  0000007fea18d170  lr  0000005df48620e8  pc  0000005df4862118
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : 
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 000000000000c118  /vendor/bin/thermald (android::CvtGovernor::CvtGovernor(android::ThermalSensor*)+628)
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000000000000b1f8  /vendor/bin/thermald (android::ThermalXmlParser::getSensorArgs(tinyxml2::XMLElement*)+708)
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 000000000000abc0  /vendor/bin/thermald (android::ThermalXmlParser::initSensorsFromXml()+876)
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000000000004998  /vendor/bin/thermald (android::ThermalManager::run()+36)
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 000000000000450c  /vendor/bin/thermald (main+64)
11-27 12:42:05.790  4779  4779 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 00000000000acd3c  /system/lib64/libc.so (__libc_init+88)
11-27 12:42:05.814   691   918 W NativeCrashListener: Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 4776
11-27 12:42:07.280   691  1026 D SSense  : onTouchRateChanged: rate:0.021484375
11-27 12:42:09.177   691   828 V NetworkStats: performPollLocked(flags=0x1)
11-27 12:42:09.198   691   828 D BroadcastQueue: Add broadcast <BroadcastRecord{737d19d u-1 com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_UPDATED}> into [parallel | background], pending size 0
11-27 12:42:09.198   691   705 D BroadcastQueue: Done with parallel broadcast [background] [BroadcastRecord{737d19d u-1 com.android.server.action.NETWORK_STATS_UPDATED}]
11-27 12:42:09.198   691   829 V NetworkPolicy: updateNetworkEnabledNL()
11-27 12:42:09.199   691   829 V NetworkPolicy: updateNotificationsNL()


11-27 12:47:06.142  5217  5217 V PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult()
11-27 12:47:06.142  5217  5217 V PythonActivity: onRequestPermissionsResult passed to callback

11-27 12:52:27.198 15855  5754 W Settings: Setting install_non_market_apps has moved from android.provider.Settings.Global to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
11-27 12:52:27.213 15855  5754 W PackageParser: Ignoring duplicate uses-permissions/uses-permissions-sdk-m: android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package: org.testapp.testapp at: Binary XML file line #29
```

Thanks!